# how do I encode links to specific archive searches?

Tags: archives

I want to embed links to the archive pages with specific search criteria. i.e Links to specific categories, links to specific authors etc etc

At the moment I am adding the links using anchor tags, but these will fail if the permalinks change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress can generate these, so you can too.  You would need to use the same function that WordPress does.

For category it would be something like:

```
$category =  get_category_by_slug( 'example' );
$link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
```

Similarly there is `get_tag_link()` and on deeper level they all really use [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)

I didn't play much with authors, but there is [`the_author_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link) and probably some `get_` analogue.

Answer (score 0):

Category archives, author archives, date archives, etc will *not* experience permalink changes.  If you're using [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#mod_rewrite%3a_.22Pretty_Permalinks.22), `http://yourblog.com/category/my-cool-category` will *always* present you with a list of posts from `my-cool-category`.  Likewise, `http://yourblog.com/author/mildfuzz` will *always* present you with a list of posts published by `mildfuzz`.

The only tricky part is if you want to display other information on the archive page (like an author bit for an author archive) ... but there are [tutorials](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) available for that kind of work.

Comment: You can change _base_ for tags and categories in permalink settings. It's rarely used, but the option is there and they can get changed.